# mysql: select query when the column that has condition on has NULL value

Tags: mysql, null, conditional-statements

This is my example table:

```
CREATE TABLE test(
name VARCHAR(35),
age INT(3))
```

And some values:

```
insert into test values ('alex', 13);
insert into test values ('dan', 17);
insert into test (name) values ('pete');
insert into test (name) values ('david');
```

When I use SELECT query with the condition on column 'age':

```
select * from test where age!=13;
```

The result I got is:

```
+------+------+
| name | age  |
+------+------+
| dan  |   17 |
+------+------+
```

But I want all the record with age!=13 which includes the record with age IS NULL too:

```
+-------+------+
| name  | age  |
+-------+------+
| dan   |   17 |
| pete  | NULL |
| david | NULL |
+-------+------+
```

How can I get what I wants? Thanks for any responding.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

```
SELECT * FROM test WHERE age!=13 OR age IS NULL;
```

Keep in mind that NULL is not really a value but more like a state. `NULL = NULL` is always false as `NULL != NULL`. Whatever you use with `NULL` will always be false. So when it evaluates `age != 13` to `NULL != 13`, it is the expected behavior to not show the row.

Comment: did you give something new or just repeat my answer ? are you a doctor in copy past things ?

Comment: @echo_Me You updated your answer by copypasting my answer. Are you a doctor in copy paste things too?

Comment: i didnt copy paste i changed `=`to `is`.

Answer (score 0):

try this

```
     select * from test where age !=13  or age is NULL;
```

Answer (score 0):

### Use the `<=>` operator.

```sql
SELECT 
  * 
FROM 
  test
WHERE
  NOT( age <=> 13 );
```

Result:

```
+-------+------+
| name  | age  |
+-------+------+
| dan   |   17 |
| pete  | NULL |
| david | NULL |
+-------+------+
```