# MySQL won't return a row with a NULL foreign key in child table

Tags: mysql, sql

I have a simple table with a foreign key and a constraint that the key must exist on the parent table.  However, the foreign-key column in this child table allows NULL.

MySQL lets me insert a row with NULL in that column and will return it on a SELECT * FROM theTable.

But if I specifically query for such a row, it won't be returned:

```
SELECT * FROM bannedItems WHERE banningAppID = NULL
```

Is this expected behavior?  I don't see this situation documented in the MySQL doc.

Comment: `SELECT * FROM bannedItems WHERE banningAppID IS NULL;`

Comment: If @wildplasser's query doesn't fix this, it is a bigger issue - Maybe your table schema, or contents aren't setup correctly

Comment: I think that's it.. and next time try to search first.. http://stackoverflow.com/questions/18748862/mysql-select-query-when-the-column-that-has-condition-on-has-null-value

Answer (score 1, accepted):

May be try like this :

```
SELECT * FROM bannedItems WHERE banningAppID IS NULL
```

or

```
SELECT * FROM bannedItems WHERE ISNULL( banningAppID )
```

And if you need to add NOT , you would do like this :

```
SELECT * FROM bannedItems WHERE banningAppID IS NOT NULL
```

or

```
SELECT * FROM bannedItems WHERE NOT ISNULL( banningAppID )
```